# Problem syncing Gmail contacts on Android tablet

Tags: contacts, sync, gmail, people-app

I have a Teac tablet (classic101) with Android 4.0.

After signing in on Gmail and Drive and everything, my contacts won't show up anywhere. It doesn't show when I start writing an address in Gmail. It doesn't even show after I downloaded contacts+ (the contacts are empty).

When I go to sync it, it suggests syncing email, calender and drive. But, there is no contacts!

How do I sync my contacts so that they will appear on my Gmail on the tablet? I have over 2000 contacts on Gmail.

It works fine on my phone, just not on the tablet.

Comment: Does the tablet have the "People" app? because if sync settings doesn't ask you to sync contacts, my guess is that there isn't a people app, or at least there isn't the "stock" people app.

Comment: thanks for the help, but yes, it does have people on it, and that doesn't sync with my contacts either although it shows that it's connected to my Gmail